# iPhone SDK 3, Interface Builder: Is it possible do deselect an element from a group of selected elements?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

Interface Builder (iPhone SDK 3): Is it possible do deselect an object from a group of selected elements by pressing some key and clicking or dragging over the object, like in Adobe Illustrator for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, hold the command key and select items that you no longer want in the group.

I suggest reading the Documentation within Xcode. It tells you basically everything you need to know, without giving you too much code. :)

Comment: That's pretty simple :) Thanks a lot. Regarding your suggestion - I agree, it is always a good thing to do :) I've just found that answer in Apple's "Interface Builder Gesture Guide"